# Namespaced API with resources specified twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm trying to create a namespaced API in rails and am running into an issue

```
  # Resources
  resources :users do 
    resources :contacts
  end

  #==========================================>
  #  API namespacing and routing
  #==========================================>

  namespace :api do 
    namespace :v1 do

      # =======================>
      # Resources -> Users
      #   Resources -> Contacts
      # =======================>
      resources :users do
        resources :contacts
      end

      # =======================>
      # Resources -> Messages 
      #   Resources -> Transcriptions
      # =======================>
      resources :messages do
        resources :transcriptions 
      end

    end
  end
```

I want to have my html-responding version of the resource outside of the 'api' namespace (i.e. in the regular app/controllers/users_controller.rb area) but my json-responding inside the namespace.

However when I point my url at the "/api/v1/users.json" link it utilizes the controller specified by the OUTSIDE resources app/controllers/users_controller rather than the one I put in app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.

Am I only allowed one resources reference despite it being namespaced differently?

Why exactly is this happending

Comment: Showing the console log output of the request/response would be helpful. Then we can see for sure which controller/view is being utilized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routing definitions look ok. The first thing I'd check is what routes are generated by your rails router by running:

```
$ bundle exec rake routes | grep users
```

You should have your defined users routes mapped to their respective URL structure. If something's amiss then your routes aren't probably defined correctly. Which i doubt in your case.

Another possible issue might be your controller class name in your namespaced users controller. So your users controller under app/controllers/api/v1 should be

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
 ....
end
```

Look at the [Rubygems.org source](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org) which has the same kind of structure you're trying to implement.

Comment: I actually omitted an important part from my problem which is that it inherited from a base_controller (which I forgot to inherit from the ApplicationController) as you stated above

Answer (score 1):

your controller should look like

```
module Api::V1
    class UserController < ActionController::Base
...
    end
end
```